# How to handle errors without URL redirection with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, error-handling

What I'm looking to do is to render custom errors without changing the URL path of the user, so using this.transitionTo is not an option.

So far the following method was working:

v1.10.1 - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tezazakiye/1/edit

But since v1.11.0, there is no way to make it works

v.1.11.3 - http://emberjs.jsbin.com/rilenafaqe/1/edit

It seems to be 'normal' according to https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10884 or https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11136 as the obtained error is:

`Error while processing route: stories.index Cannot read property 'push' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

If I well understood, it is normal, not being able to call render() from the error action now, but what is the good way to do it then?

(I've also posted on github: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11282)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it fits your criteria, but you can bubble up the action so that applicationRoute handles your error action like in here : http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pehanoveko/1/

Comment: It's a nice workaround event if it's not the solution I'm looking for, if I can avoid to bubble up all errors to the root Route, I would prefer. Thanks you for your help.